# Unit Testing Sitecore using NUnit, serializing content

Tags: .net, unit-testing, sitecore, sitecore6

In my business, I am working on Unit Testing, after finishing an example in a .NET application. We want to use a standard .NET Unit Testing project. We also want to mock the Sitecore data by serializing the Sitecore objects. I have been looking for, but could not find a good tutorial to do this. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesting videos on Youtube

1. Sitecore Unit Testing [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXAaog1Ej8Y) by gravypower.
2. Another [interesting video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZKSl3pemEs) by codeflood.
3. Most knowledgeable for me was this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQ2CPvN9FAU) by [Alistair Deneys](https://twitter.com/adeneys) from [Hedgehog](http://www.hhogdev.com/)

Other interesting blogs are

1. [Igloo - Unit Testing for Sitecore](http://www.igloo.com.au/blog/unit-testing-for-sitecore/)
2. [iStern - Unit testing with Sitecore Item](http://blog.istern.dk/2012/02/07/unit-testing-with-sitecore-item/) by [Thomas Stern](https://twitter.com/Thomas_Stern/)
3. Mocking Sitecore with MS Fakes [Part I](http://blog.istern.dk/2013/04/08/mocking-sitecore-with-microsoft-fakes-part-1/) and [Part II](http://blog.istern.dk/2013/04/10/mocking-sitecore-with-microsoft-fakes-part-2/) by [Thomas Stern](https://twitter.com/Thomas_Stern/)
4. And lastly my preferred [Coffee => Coder => Code](http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2010/11/20/unit-testing-in-sitecore-is-not-scary/) again by Alistair Deneys
5. [Knifecore's blog](http://hermanussen.eu/sitecore/wordpress/2012/06/sitecore-unit-testing-with-test-fixtures/) also helped me a lot when I was trying to write tests.

Let us know if this was helpful.

If you are interested in Serialization, [Kern Nightingale](https://twitter.com/herskinduk) has got a [perfect presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mFdoPZmpU0) which will give you insight to how to use it for testing as well.

Finally would also recommend [Sitecore Glimpse](https://github.com/kevinobee/Sitecore.Glimpse) by [Kevin Obee](https://twitter.com/KevinObee), the project's one of the purpose is "***provide build scripts that automate the tasks of compiling, testing and packaging the project artifacts to make it easier to open the project up for collaborative development***" which he mentions on his [blog](http://kevinobee.wordpress.com/2013/08/25/glimpse-for-sitecore/).

Comment: Don't forget the presentation from todays Sitecore Virtual Summit :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_iuvYAtig8 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PR595c2_rM